# Left inverse proof

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

If we let $A$ be a $m\times n$ matrix and let $B$ be a $n\times p$ matrix. Suppose that both $A$ and $B$ have a left inverse. Show that $AB$ has a left inverse.

i know that matrix $A^T$A is an invertible $n$ by $n$ symmetric matrix. Hence. $(A^T)^{-1}A^TA = I$. So then $A_{\text{left}}^{-1} = (A^TA)^{-1}A^T$

But how do I go about proving that $AB$ has a left inverse?

Comment: Directly use the definition of left inverse: a matrix $L$ such that $LA=I_n$. Take $MB=I_p$ and try what happens with $(ML)(AB)$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: Try computing $(B_{\text{left}}^{-1}A_{\text{left}}^{-1})(AB)$. What do you get?

Comment: @ parsiad how do you compute that?

Comment: @mtphys Just with the definition of left inverse, and associativity. e.g. $A_{\text{left}}^{-1} A = I$

Comment: @ arkeet$(B_{\text{left}}^{-1}A_{\text{left}}^{-1})(AB) = I^2$??

Comment: @mtphys: $I^2=I$

Comment: @ parsiad. So since it equals I is that enough for the proof?

Comment: @geohelp: well, I think you should really convince yourself that, but yes.